# Storing session in Browser for express.js (MERN Stack)

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

I've been trying to store a user's email in the session for my express.js file. But everytime I try something, and call another function, the session remains undefined. I wanted to store it in the browser only without storing each session in the database. Been working on this for weeks now, and I can't seem to find the answer.

server.js file:

```
import express from 'express';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import session from 'express-session';
const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        maxAge  : 1000 * 60 * 60 * 3, // if 1 day * 24 but since *3 its for 3 hours only
    },
}))

app.post('/user/login', (req, res) => { 
    const loginUser = req.body;
    const email = loginUser['email'];
    const password = loginUser['password'];
    if (!email || !password){ 
        res.status(400).json({success: false, error: "Please provide email and password"});
    }
    try { 
        Users.findOne({ email: email }, (err, user) => { 
            if (password == user['password']){
                req.session.user(user['email']);
                res.status(200).send(user_email);
            } else {
                res.status(400).json({success: false, error: "incorrect password"});
            }
        });
    } catch { 
    }
})
```

Calling the Login file from the frontend (react js):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Grid, TextField, Button } from '@mui/material';
import "./SignUpLogin.css";
import axios from '../../axios';
import useForm from './useForm';
import { Form } from './useForm';


const initialValues = { 
    email: '',
    password: ''
}

function Login({ modalFunc }) { 

    const LoginUser = e => { 
        console.log("INSIDE LOGIN USER");
        modalFunc();
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.post('/user/login', values, {withCredentials: true})
            .then(response => { 
                console.log("in login user");
                console.log(response.data);
            })
    }

    const {
        values, 
        setValues, 
        handleInputChange
    } = useForm(initialValues);

    return (
        <div className="Login">
            <Form> 
                <Grid item>
                    <TextField
                        required 
                        variant="outlined"
                        label="Email"
                        name="email"
                        color="secondary"
                        fullWidth
                        value={ values.email } 
                        onChange={ handleInputChange }
                    />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                    <TextField 
                    required 
                        variant="outlined"
                        label="Password"
                        name="password"
                        type="password"
                        color="secondary"
                        fullWidth
                        value={ values.password }
                        onChange={ handleInputChange }
                    />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item> 
                    <Button 
                        variant="contained"
                        fullWidth
                        onClick = { LoginUser }>
                    Login
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </Form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

But when I call server.js again in another get function, session is undefined.

```
app.get('/user/loggedIn', (req, res) => { 
    console.log(req.session.user);
    user_email = req.session.user;
    if (req.session.user) {
        Users.findOne({ email: user_email }, (err, user) => { 
            // console.log("in logged in, in server!!!");
            // console.log(user);
            res.status(200).send(user);
        })
    } else { 
        console.log("no session");
        res.status(400);
    }
})
```

Calling app.get('/user/loggedIn') in react.js file:

```
function Header() {
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false); 
  const changeModal = () => { 
    setModalOpen(!modalOpen)
  }

  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => { 
    // axios.get('/user/loggedIn', {}, {withCredentials: true})
    axios.get('/user/loggedIn', {}, {withCredentials: true})
    .then(response => { 
      // console.log("RESPONSE FROM LOGGED IN");
      // console.log(response.data);
      setUser(response.data);
    })
  })
```

Comment: You are using  `express-session` middleware and its documentation http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html explicitly says:  "Session data is not saved in the cookie itself, just the session ID. Session data is stored **server-side**.". You are trying to use the module for something it was not designed for.

Comment: Hi! Oh got it. So which approach should I use if I would just like to store session in the browser?

Comment: Find a middleware that stores session in the browser or write your own. I wouldn't recommend it tho. Sessions are usually stored serverside and are considered a trusted source. Your "browser session" can be used by other components of the framework written in assumption the session is standard. You risk exposing private information and remote code execution vulnerability.  It's not clear what you aim to gain with browser session, so be a ware of the hidden cost of this approach.

Comment: Got it!!!! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

**server.js**

```
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",
        credentials: true,
    })
);
```

**withCredentials should be defined this way**

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```